# Approximating the *conditional* probability of 1D discrete random walk not having revisited the origin given last position

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, markov-chains, random-walks

I'm looking for a good closed form approximation to the following conditional probability, with provable approximation guarantees.

Consider a 1D random walk on the integers, starting at the origin, each step going either $+1$ or $-1$ (the bias is irrelevant to the conditional probability I have in mind, but say it's probability $1/2$ either way). What I want to know is that, conditional on the walk ending up at point $N$ at time $T$, what is the probability that the walk never revisited the origin (other than the very first time point)? One could, of course, write out recurrences to compute such a probability algorithmically, but I'm hoping for some good closed form approximation.

The bias doesn't matter because ending up at point $N$ at time $T$ fixes the number of $+1$s and $-1$s in the walk, so really I'm asking for the proportion of the permutations of $\pm 1$s that do not revisit the origin.

Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly what [reflection principle](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~breed/MATH671/lecture2corrected.pdf) was invented for.

Comment: Whoops, thank you.

Comment: The answer is $N/T$. This is called the *ballot theorem,* see for example my lecture notes here (and, as Mateusz pointed out, it follows from the reflection lemma): http://www2.math.ou.edu/~cremling/teaching/lecturenotes/ln-rw.pdf